# how can i return an array of strings in graphQL - proper setup?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

Hi I am trying to figure out why I am not returning an array of strings. I have read the docs and i must say, im stuck im a bit new to this sorry for the dumb question but can someone please help me figure this out?

I cant seem to get "flickr_images": to return an array of strings. I dont know how to proceed from there. "flicker_images" constantly return null.

I setup my graphql schema like this
`

```
const LaunchType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Launch',
  fields: () => ({
    flight_number: { type: GraphQLInt },
    mission_name: { type: GraphQLString },
    launch_year: { type: GraphQLString },
    launch_date_local: { type: GraphQLString },
    launch_success: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
    details: { type: GraphQLString },
    rocket: { type: RocketType },
    launch_site: { type: LaunchSite },
    links: { type: UrlType },
  }),
});
```

```
const RocketType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Rocket',
  fields: () => ({
    rocket_id: { type: GraphQLString },
    rocket_name: { type: GraphQLString },
    rocket_type: { type: GraphQLString },
  }),
});
```

```
const UrlType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Url',
  fields: () => ({
    mission_patch_small: { type: GraphQLString },
    flickr_images: { type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString) },
  }),
});
```

```
 rocket: {
      type: RocketType,
      args: {
        id: { type: GraphQLInt },
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return axios
          .get(`https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/rockets/${args.id}`)
          .then((res) => res.data);
      },
    },
links: {
      type: UrlType,
      args: {
        flight_number: { type: GraphQLInt },
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return axios
          .get(`https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches/${args.flight_number}`)
          .then((res) => res.data);
      },
    },
```

`

UPDATED

Comment: I'm guessing that `axios.get(`https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/rockets/${args.id}`)` isn't returning an array of flickr images as part of its payload. You're going to need a separate resolver under  your `rocket` to resolve that field.

Comment: Thank you very much Michel, I created a new object type and made a separate resolve to links under rocket and now it works! I was using the wrong end point also but when i double checked i noticed i should have used launches/${args.flight_number} instead of /rockets/${args.id}

Comment: I'll convert that into an answer.

Comment: In the spirit of shameless promotion, you might enjoy my posts on [GraphQL for SQL developers](https://michelfloyd.hashnode.dev/graphql-for-sql-developers-part-1).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `axios.get(api.spacexdata.com/v3/rockets/${args.id})` isn't returning an array of flickr images as part of its payload. You're going to need a separate resolver under your `rocket` to resolve that field.